# How to get the length of String[][] Array

Tags: java, android, string, multidimensional-array

I have a `String[][]` type array, like this,

```
static final String arrChildelements[][] = {
    { "1", "2", "3"..... },
    { "A", "B", "C"..... },
    { "X", "Y", "Z"..... } };
```

Here the number of rows is fixed i.e. 3. Now I want to store this Array in some other Array of the same type. What I have done so far is,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondColumnLength; j++) { 
           //Here I have no idea that how to get the number of elements for the column
            arrChild[i][j] = arrChildelements[i][j];
        }
    }
```

So far, I can only remember this method to iterate through the `String[][]` array. Though I would love to know if there is any other good way to accomplish this.

Comment: You need to use loop at least one time, inside the loop you can use Copyof http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[], int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over each member of an array, instead use `System.arraycopy()`:

```
System.arraycopy(arrChildElements, 0, arrChild, 0, arrChildElements.length);
```

Additionally, if you must iterate over each value, `arrChildElements.length` is your outer loop value, and `arrChildElements[i].length` is your inner loop value.

Comment: Simply Awesome. Thanx never before heard of **arraycopy()**. but it work wonders.

Answer (score 1):

`arrChildelements.length` is the number of rows 
`arrChildelements[i].length` is the number of columns in row i.

And it keeps working like that for more dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrChildElements.length = length of first dimension
arrChildElements[].length = length of second dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrChildelements.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrChildelements[i].length; j++) { 
        arrChild[i][j] = arrChildelements[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is more or less what he wants to avoid